# I want to extract the text from a Google Doc using an extension in the browser and preserve semantic line breaks

Tags: javascript, google-docs

I have a browser extension (Firefox and Chrome) that works much like a spell checker. It mostly works fine when getting text values from `input` and `textarea` and even most `contenteditable` elements. However Google Docs likes to insert `\n` for visual reasons which makes getting semantic paragraphs and sentences challenging.

e.g. the text:

```
A Long Heading That Visually Wraps With No Period On The End
 
A sentence that runs long enough that it visually wraps in Google Docs and ends up with extra line breaks. Another shorter sentence.
```

when extracted from the Google Docs DOM and run through `JSON.stringify` shows up thus:

```
"\"A Long Heading That Visually Wraps \\nWith No Period On The End \\n  \\nA sentence that runs long enough that it visually wraps in Google Docs and ends up with extra \\nline breaks. Another shorter sentence.\""
```

Note the `\\n` before `With` which is not semantic, then the `\\n \\n` after the headline which is semantic, and then the `\\n` before `line` which again is not semantic.

In this specific case I can `text.replace(/\n \n/g, '!!!').replace(/\n/g, '').replace(/!!!/g, '\n\n')` to get a (more) semantic body of text back.

However if there is no double `\n` after the heading then it doesn't work.

You can see how fragile it can be.

Is there a JavaScript DOM/API for a Google Doc that doesn't require extra authorisation so that I can get the clean text of a document? The user has already installed this extension and having to also authorise an app for their Google Drive is not viable.

Alternatively is there a JavaScript sentence tokenizer? Otherwise I'm going to have to ship off the raw text to a Python API endpoint using NTLK/spaCy sentence tokenizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether the document you want to extract the data is public or not, your application might require authorization or not for extracting the clean data.

In either way, using the [Document App of Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app) or even the [Documents API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api) are both great options to obtain the clean body data and even to select titles, subtitles and so on providing further functionalities than just extracting the document text data.

**NOTE**: If you try to access a Document that is **not** public you will need to use [oAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2). Since it isn't a public resource, you are required to use the credentials of an account that has access to this resource.

Comment: Thanks Mateo, I know of Apps Script and Documents API but I can't use either of those from the browser extension without asking the user to authorise a new app. As the browser extension is running inside the Google Docs tab I was hoping to have some access to the document API.

Comment: Unless the document of your user is public, you will need the user to authorise with oAuth 2.0 either for the use of the Apps Script application or Documents API. I have updated my answer with further detail on this.

Comment: Thanks Mateo, seems like I am asking for the impossible. Without authorised API access to the doc we're going to go with extracting sentences using spaCy/NLTK which are more robust than lots of JavaScript regex.